# Manage VS Team Services Boards from mobile phone

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to manage the cards of my VS Team Services boards from my mobile phone. This way I can add issue when I am at customer sites and check the development of other, move features to more urgent columns.

Is there a mobile app (for Android prefered, but I ask in general)? Is there an app for on-premise team services and/or visual studio online team services?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use your browser to manage your visual studio team services projects - cards, boards and etc. Chrome on Android-phone are working very good for every proposes. You can also setup to publish your build or release results at slack.

Unfortunately, no official mobile client as an app.
But you can search and find many unofficial clients at Play market.
But of course without any warranty.

Comment: While the site works in the Chrome browser, it is not optimized for it. Furthermore especially moving the cards is hard or impossible. I would appreciate app recommendations even when not from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

There is no official mobile app for VSTS. But there is already a user voice submitted here: [Mobile App for Visual Studio Online/TFS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/9519951-mobile-app-for-visual-studio-online-tfs). You can vote it. MS will review these feature requests.